# Pandas: aggregate some rows of DataFrame preserving order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame:

`Time   Event   ID  Volume  Price   Direction   Ask Ask_Volume  Bid Bid_Volume
37800.010780    3   58438512    100 2165800 -1  2166100 201 2163900 100
37800.750437    3   58430272    100 2166100 -1  2166100 101 2163900 100
37801.509857    1   58497163    100 2165800 -1  2165800 100 2163900 100
37802.003067    1   58512077    100 2164100 1   2165800 100 2164100 100
37802.448190    3   58512077    100 2164100 1   2165800 100 2163400 100`

I want to only aggregate by 'Time' those rows that have 'Event' == 4 or 'Event' == 5 as following:

```
.agg({'Event': 'first', 'Order_ID': 'first','Volume': 'sum','Price': 
'first', 'Direction': 'first','Ask': 'last','Ask_Volume': 'last', 
'Bid': 'last','Bid_Volume': 'last'}).reset_index()
```

However, there are rows being aggregated that don't meet condition of 'Event' == 4 or 'Event' == 5.

I've tried

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Time'): 
   if (group.iloc[0]['Event'] == 4) or (group.iloc[0]['Event'] == 5):
    group.agg({'Event': 'first', 'Order_ID': 'first',
                     'Volume': 'sum',
                     'Price': 'first', 'Direction': 'first',
                     'Ask': 'last',
                     'Ask_Volume': 'last', 'Bid': 'last',
                     'Bid_Volume': 'last'})
    print(group)
```

**Given Result:**

```
Time    Event   Order_ID    Volume  Price   Direction   Ask Ask_Volume  Bid Bid_Volume

38092.61611 1   62704661    100 2152200 -1  2152200 100 2152100 222
38092.61620 4   62704661    100 2152200 -1  2153200 500 2152100 222
38092.61694 4   62652001    79  2152100 1   2153200 500 2152100 143
38092.61694 4   62669938    43  2152100 1   2153200 500 2152100 100
38092.61694 4   62699302    14  2152100 1   2153200 500 2152100 86
38092.61695 4   62699302    86  2152100 1   2153200 500 2150800 100
38092.61744 1   62704696    100 2153000 -1  2153000 100 2150800 100`
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Time    Event   Order_ID    Volume  Price   Direction   Ask Ask_Volume  Bid Bid_Volume

38092.61611 1   62704661    100 2152200 -1  2152200 100 2152100 222
38092.61620 4   62704661    100 2152200 -1  2153200 500 2152100 222
38092.61694 4   62699302    136 2152100 1   2153200 500 2152100 86
38092.61695 4   62699302    86  2152100 1   2153200 500 2150800 100
38092.61744 1   62704696    100 2153000 -1  2153000 100 2150800 100
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried: 1) printing `group.iloc[0]['Event']` to see what it logs? 2) edit if statement equal to `'4'` instead of `4`? These are just suggestions and I cannot confirm if they will work since I am not able to test your code.

Comment: Your expected output has events equal to neither 4 nor 5.

Comment: The data you have posted & the answer you have posted are completely different. can you post the expected answer for your posted data?